# ConTeXt MarkIV : Arabic Letters are disjointed and reversed in headers and margin

Tags: fonts, header-footer, context, context-mkiv, arabic

I am trying to get Arabic Chapter Name in the header and some arabic text in the margins using ConTeXt MarkIV

Here is the MWE:

```
\mainlanguage[arabic]
\setupdirections[bidi=global]
\definefontfeature
  [arabic]
  [mode=node,language=dflt,script=arab,
    init=yes,medi=yes,fina=yes,isol=yes,
    liga=yes,dlig=yes,rlig=yes,tlig=yes,
    calt=yes,trep=yes,clig=yes,
    mark=yes,mkmk=yes,kern=yes,curs=yes]


\starttypescript [serif] [arabic]
  \definefontsynonym [Arabic-Regular] [file:ScheherazadeRegOT.ttf] [features=arabic]
  \definefontsynonym [Arabic-Bold] [file:ScheherazadeRegOT.ttf] [features=arabic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [serif] [arabic] [name]
 \usetypescript[serif][fallback]
 \definefontsynonym [Serif]     [Arabic-Regular] [features=arabic]
 \definefontsynonym [SerifBold] [Arabic-Bold]    [features=arabic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [Arabic]
  \definetypeface [Arabic] [rm] [serif] [arabic] [default] 
\stoptypescript 

\def\ArabicGlobalDir {\pagedir TRT\bodydir TRT\pardir TRT\textdir TRT}
\def\ArabicParDir    {\textdir TRT\pardir TRT}
\def\ArabicTextDir   {\textdir TRT}

\define\setarabic
  {\ArabicGlobalDir%
   \usetypescript[Arabic]%
   \setupbodyfont[Arabic,20pt]}

\definestartstop
  [arabicpar]
  [commands=\Arabic\ArabicParDir]

\define[1]\RT
  {{\Arabic\ArabicTextDir#1}}

\pagedir TRT
\bodydir TRT
\pardir TRT
\textdir TRT

\setuppapersize[A4]

\setuplayout[
  grid=min,
  backspace=55.999mm, width=130mm,
  topspace=39.666mm, height=210mm,
  header=12mm, footer=9mm,
  ]

\setupbodyfont[Arabic,24pt]
\setupinterlinespace[line=42pt]

\setupheads[number=no]
\setuphead[chapter][style=\bfd,before=,after=\blank,alternative=middle,grid=both]
\setuphead[section][style=\bfc,before=\blank,after=,grid=both]

\setupbackgrounds[header][text][frame=off, bottomframe=on]

\setupheadertexts
        [{\getmarking[chapter]}]    [{صفحة }]
        [{صفحة }]        [{\getmarking[chapter]}]

\setupinmargin[stack=yes]

\starttext

\chapter{الآجرومية}

\margintext{الآجرومية}

الحمد لله رب العالمين، وصلى الله وسلم وبارك على عبده ورسوله نبينا محمد وعلى آله وصحبه أجمعين، أما بعد:
فلا يخفى على من له أدنى عناية بالعلم الشرعي لا سيما ما يتعلق بالكتاب العزيز والسنة النبوية لا يخفى عليه أهمية معرفة اللغة العربية بفنونها العشرة أو الإثني عشر: 

\stoptext
```

I tried searching in the ConTeXt manual and here, but could not get any solutions.

[image: Header Issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution from ConTeXt Mailing List answered by Hans.

> ```
> \setupmargindata[margintext]
> [align=r2l]
>
> \setupalign[r2l]  
>
> \setupheader[style=\righttoleft, state=normal]
> ```

The above solution works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have little knowledge of how to write arabic with context, usually I use `polyglossia`, appear that you have  defined command to write right to left text `\ArabicTextDir`, you can use it to resolve the problem with:

```
\setupheadertexts [{\getmarking[chapter]}] [{\ArabicTextDir صفحة}][{صفحة }] [{\getmarking[chapter]}]
```

and

```
\chapter{\ArabicTextDir الآجرومية}
```

---

**Code**

```
\mainlanguage[arabic]
\setupdirections[bidi=global]
\definefontfeature
  [arabic]
  [mode=node,language=dflt,script=arab,
    init=yes,medi=yes,fina=yes,isol=yes,
    liga=yes,dlig=yes,rlig=yes,tlig=yes,
    calt=yes,trep=yes,clig=yes,
    mark=yes,mkmk=yes,kern=yes,curs=yes]


\starttypescript [serif] [arabic]
  \definefontsynonym [Arabic-Regular] [file:ScheherazadeRegOT.ttf] [features=arabic]
  \definefontsynonym [Arabic-Bold] [file:ScheherazadeRegOT.ttf] [features=arabic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [serif] [arabic] [name]
 \usetypescript[serif][fallback]
 \definefontsynonym [Serif]     [Arabic-Regular] [features=arabic]
 \definefontsynonym [SerifBold] [Arabic-Bold]    [features=arabic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [Arabic]
  \definetypeface [Arabic] [rm] [serif] [arabic] [default] 
\stoptypescript 

\def\ArabicGlobalDir {\pagedir TRT\bodydir TRT\pardir TRT\textdir TRT}
\def\ArabicParDir    {\textdir TRT\pardir TRT}
\def\ArabicTextDir   {\textdir TRT}

\define\setarabic
  {\ArabicGlobalDir%
   \usetypescript[Arabic]%
   \setupbodyfont[Arabic,20pt]}

\definestartstop
  [arabicpar]
  [commands=\Arabic\ArabicParDir]

\define[1]\RT
  {{\Arabic\ArabicTextDir#1}}

\pagedir TRT
\bodydir TRT
\pardir TRT
\textdir TRT

\setuppapersize[A4]

\setuplayout[
  grid=min,
  backspace=55.999mm, width=130mm,
  topspace=39.666mm, height=210mm,
  header=12mm, footer=9mm,
  ]

\setupbodyfont[Arabic,24pt]
\setupinterlinespace[line=42pt]

\setupheads[number=no]
\setuphead[chapter][style=\bfd,before=,after=\blank,alternative=middle,grid=both]
\setuphead[section][style=\bfc,before=\blank,after=,grid=both]

\setupbackgrounds[header][text][frame=off, bottomframe=on]

\setupheadertexts
        [{\getmarking[chapter]}]    [{\ArabicTextDir صفحة}]
        [{صفحة }]        [{\getmarking[chapter]}]

\setupinmargin[stack=yes]

\starttext

\chapter{\ArabicTextDir الآجرومية}

\margintext{الآجرومية}

الحمد لله رب العالمين، وصلى الله وسلم وبارك على عبده ورسوله نبينا محمد وعلى آله وصحبه أجمعين، أما بعد:
فلا يخفى على من له أدنى عناية بالعلم الشرعي لا سيما ما يتعلق بالكتاب العزيز والسنة النبوية لا يخفى عليه أهمية معرفة اللغة العربية بفنونها العشرة أو الإثني عشر: 

\stoptext
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Your solution works as well. I found a shorter version from ConTeXt mailing list.